# How to do a conditional rolling mean in Pandas?

Tags: pandas, window, apply, rolling-computation

I have this data frame available. It has a timestamp for start, a timestamp for end and a duration column.

| start | end | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 | 2 |
| 5 | 9 | 4 |
| 6 | 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 10 | 3 |

I'd like to add a column 'rolling_mean' to the dataframe that calculates a rolling average on all previous rows (ordered by start) with this condition: only previous rows can be used for mean calculation where the event has already ended (so end date should be equal to or lower than the start date of the row for which the rolling mean is being calculated). So for row number 4, the rolling_mean is 1 because we look at all previous rows and only the previous one fulfills the condition of the event having ended.
This is the dataframe I'd like to get with a Pandas rolling mean:

| start | end | duration | rolling_mean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 4 | Nan |
| 2 | 5 | 3 | Nan |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | Nan |
| 4 | 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 9 | 4 | 2.666667 |
| 6 | 7 | 1 | 2.500000 |
| 7 | 10 | 3 | 2.200000 |

Here is the code to reproduce my example:

```
d = [[1, 5],
[2, 5],
[3, 4],
[4, 6],
[5, 9],
[6, 7],
[7, 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=['start_time', 'end_time'])
df['duration'] = df.end_time - df.start_time
```

I've tried to merge the dataframe with itself to then filter out the irrelevant rows, but the data frame is too big to take this approach.

So I'm looking for a rolling mean but where I can specify the extra condition.
Does anyone have any ideas for this one?

Answer (score 0):

A for loop will do the job:

```py
rolling_mean = np.repeat(np.nan, len(df))
start, end, duration = df[["start_time", "end_time", "duration"]].to_numpy().T

for i in range(len(df)):
    matches = duration[:i][end[:i] <= start[i]]
    if matches.any():
        rolling_mean[i] = matches.mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I wonder if there is a way to avoid looping over a huge dataframe... Maybe with a lambda function? Not very familiar with them, so I'm not sure

Comment: Or maybe with a custom apply function on the rolling object?

Comment: This case calls for an *expanding function*, which is a kind of rolling function (rolling from the top to the current row). A custom rolling function is the same as a for loop. You gain nothing performance-wise. If `start` and `end` are monotonous increasing, you can optimize this to `O(n)` and then further speed it up using Cython or numba.